# How can I branch a solution with multiple projects referenced in VS.Net using TFS Version Control

Tags: visual-studio, branch, tfvc

I have one main Web project that references multiple projects.
These projects are shared with other solutions.
Each project has its own workspace area in Azure Devops (VS Online)
I'm using Team Foundation Version Control (TFVC, not Git)

When I need to create a branch of this Web project, I manually:

- Create a branch of this Web project
- For each referenced project I create a branch
- Open the Web project branch newly created and adjust its references to the branched projects

It takes I lot of time!

How can I branch this Web project and all its referenced projects (considering that each one has its own workspace area) in a practical way?